# The unicode-math package messes up MnSymbol symbols

Tags: packages, unicode-math, mnsymbol

Using TeXLive 2015.

The commands `\lsem` and `\rsem` of `MnSymbol` don’t work when the package `unicode-math` is loaded. Compare the codes, with `unicode-math`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}  
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{MnSymbol} 

 \begin{document} 
  With unicode-math: $\lsem x \rsem$
 \end{document}
```

and without `unicode-math`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}  
%\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{MnSymbol} 

 \begin{document} 
  Without unicode-math: $\lsem x \rsem$
 \end{document}
```

as well as their respective outputs:

[image: with unicode-math]
[image: without unicode-math]

*Question*. How can I fix this and use `\lsem` and `\rsem` as inteded?

Comment: `MnSymbol` is surely incompatible with `unicode-math`.

Comment: @egreg Ok, what do you suggest?

Comment: See also [the bug report](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/issues/32), alas.

Comment: What do you need `unicode-math` for? Or, conversely, what do you need `MnSymbol` for?

Comment: @egreg From `unicode-math`, I use the xits font and I type in some unicode math characters. I use `MnSymbols` for delimiters and other math symbols I can’t type in directly (actually I’m not sure for what I use `MnSymbols` – I have made a lot of math definitions a while ago and I don’t know anymore which of them use this package).

Comment: I can think how the packages could coexist, but with *extensive* work, I'm afraid.

Comment: @k.tsm `\lsem` and `\rsem` are also available in the XITS font as `\lBrack` and `\rBrack`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Ah, nice! Works like a charm. (If you read my previous, now deleted comment: Disregard it, I made a mistake.) You can make an answer out of this and I’ll upvote it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton See my last comment. Sorry for the mix-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MnSymbol` aims at changing *all* math symbols, using its own. For this it redefines the standard math families to use its fonts. In particular it does

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}  {OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}       {U}  {MnSymbolF}{m}{n}
```

but these declarations are later overridden by `unicode-math`, so when something is using the `largesymbols` math group, it ends up with a character in the current Unicode math font.

Making the package compatible with `unicode-math` means changing all symbol definitions using `largesymbols` and `symbols` to be different. For getting your `\lsem` and `\rsem`, you can do like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MNlargesymbols}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}
\makeatletter
\Decl@Mn@Open {\lsem}{MNlargesymbols}{'102}
\Decl@Mn@Close{\rsem}{MNlargesymbols}{'107}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
With unicode-math: $\lsem x \rsem$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may need more redefinitions, but they're as easy as these ones: just look for the needed symbol's definition in `MnSymbol.sty`.

Answer (score 2):

`\lsem` and `\rsem` are also available in the XITS font as `\lBrack` and `\rBrack`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
$\lBrack x \rBrack$
\end{document}
```

> [image]